# How to expand the diff view in gitkraken

Tags: gitkraken

My case looks like this. There is a very large feature branch that adds, removes and modifies a lot (almost 400) files.

My task is to review all of the changes, mainly to make sure that all of the changes are reflected in appropriate tests.

Gitkraken has this neat feature that allows to show diff between two commits of any branch. So a natural thing to do is to click on two commits (tip of my feature branch and master). Nice, but given the context I'd like to show only this diff window since I don't need any of the swimlane/commit view. And all I can to is to expand the right pane to 1/3 of the window width.

I am using the tree view so the 1/3 is not enough BTW

Any ideas how to display it as a separate window/maximize the pane to 100% of the window width?

UPDATE: I can get 50% of screen witdh by tiling the window to half of a screen: swimlane/diff layout switches then to horizontal and I expand the diff to 100% of height

UPDATE 2: I can get 66% of screen width
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear which panel you're talking of. The list of files? You can expand that to about 2/3rds of the screen by pinning it to the bottom and dragging the top border up. I think that might be what you already did. You can also collapse the branch view on the left by clicking the little arrow on top of the panel. Doing that, the file view will cover about 90% of your screen width.

If that was the panel you meant, switching from `Path` to `Tree`view might also help

Or do you mean the diff itself, showing in-file changes? Collapsing the branch view on the left also helps here, although there's no way I know of to hide the file view on the right panel.

EDIT:

### Final answer

"Pinning to the bottom", as mentioned above, is available via button since GitKraken release 3.1.0. This allows to pin the desired panel to the bottom when GK is in full screen mode. Collapsing the branch view as described will then result in the panel using >90% screen width.

From [GitKraken release notes](https://support.gitkraken.com/release-notes/current):

> We’ve given the commit panel a Cinderella-style makeover!  It has a
>   new header and can be pinned to the right or bottom of the window as
>   you prefer.

Comment: I want the "showing diff between 2 commits" to take as much as possible

Comment: Added the screenshot

Comment: In addition to what is shown in your screenshot, I am able to increase the size further by dragging above the "Viewing diff between 2 commits", which makes the diff view disappear and makes the panel you're interested in cover the whole screen. I'm working in windows, though, so this might not work in your environment. Or it might only be available if you install a GK update, you do not seem to have the most up-to-date version. I'm on 3.3.2.

Comment: I am a able to do that as well, but I am interested in 100% of width, because of the tree view.

Comment: But the panel in your screenshot is at 100% of GKs width. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Yes, but please take a look at my updates. I get this layout mode (vertical panels) only when I resize the GK window to 2/3 of my FullHD screen. So what I want is to be able to use this layout on resolutions 1080p and higher. BTW I am almost done with the task requiring this but it would be nice to know if there is a way to do it in case someone needs this for the future

Comment: Ah, I didn't quite understand that part right. In that case, you should definitely update your GK. There was an update that introduced a button to switch between vertical and horizontal panel view.

Comment: good to know, thanks. Please update your post so I can mark is as an answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163647/discussion-between-kowsky-and-peuczynski).